# I need to replace a string in one file using key value paris from another file

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I have a single attribute file that has two columns. The string in column 1 matches the string in the files that need to be changed. The string in file 2 needs to be the string in file 1 column 2.

I'm not sure the best way to approach this sed? awk? There is only a single file 1 that has every key and value pair, they are all unique. There are over 10,000 File 2, that are each different but have the same format, that I would need to change from the numbers to the names. Every number in any of the File 2's will be in File 1.

File 1

```
1000079541  ALBlai_CCA27168
1000079542  ALBlai_CCA27169
1000082614  PHYsoj_128987
1000082623  PHYsoj_128997
1000112581  PHYcap_Phyca_508162
1000112588  PHYcap_Phyca_508166
1000112589  PHYcap_Phyca_508170
1000112592  PHYcap_Phyca_549547
1000120087  HYAara_HpaP801280
1000134210  PHYinf_PITG_01218T0
1000134213  PHYinf_PITG_01223T0
1000134221  PHYinf_PITG_01231T0
1000144497  PHYinf_PITG_13921T0
1000153541  PYTultPYU1_T002777
1000162512  PYTultPYU1_T013706
1000163504  PYTultPYU1_T014907
1000168326  PHYram_79731
1000168327  PHYram_79730
1000168332  PHYram_79725
1000168335  PHYram_79722
...
```

File 2

```
(1000079542:0.60919245567850022205,((1000162512:0.41491233674846345059,(1000153541:0.39076742568979516701,1000163504:0.52813999143574519302):0.14562273102476630537):0.28880212838980307000,(((1000144497:0.20364901110426453235,1000168327:0.22130795712572320921):0.35964649479701132906,((1000120087:0.34990382691181332042,(1000112588:0.08084123331549526725,(1000168332:0.12176200773214326811,1000134213:0.09481932223544080329):0.00945982345360765406):0.01846847662360769429):0.19758412044470402558,((1000168326:0.06182031367986642878,1000112589:0.07837371928562210377):0.03460740736793390532,(1000134210:0.13512192366876615846,(1000082623:0.13344777464787777044,1000112592:0.14943677128375676411):0.03425386814075986885):0.05235436818005634318):0.44112430521695145114):0.21763784827666701749):0.22507080810857052477,(1000112581:0.02102132893524749635,(1000134221:0.10938436290969000275,(1000082614:0.05263067805665807425,1000168335:0.07681947209386902342):0.03562545894572662769):0.02623229853693959113):0.49114147006852687527):0.23017851954961116023):0.64646763541457552549,1000079541:0.90035900920746847476):0.0;
```

Desired Result

```
(ALBlai_CCA27169:0.60919245567850022205,((PYTultPYU1_T013706:0.41491233674846345059, ...
```

Comment: How do you know which parts of `File 2` to replace? What's the "format" of `File 2`?

Comment: The portion to replace will always end with a `:` and will be preceded with either a `(` or a `,` there are situations were there is more than a singe preceding `(` Each file 2 is a single line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python:

```
import re

# Build a dictionary of replacements:
with open('File 1') as f:
    repl = dict(line.split() for line in f)

# Read in the file and make the replacements:
with open('File 2') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = re.sub(r'(\d+):',lambda m: repl[m.group(1)]+':',data)

# Write it back out:
with open('File 2','w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: how do you itterate this over 10,000 of file 2? They all end in .tre can we use a wildcard for `File 2`

Comment: This doesn't ensure require a preceding `(` or `,` on the match and so may get things wrong. This also fails if the matched number doesn't have an entry in `File 1` (I don't know if that can happen here but in general it is something to be concerned about).

Comment: `os.walk` or `glob.glob` can be used to iterate files.

Comment: @etanreisner, the OP stated every number in file two will be in file one. Also lacking specific file two syntax matching digits to left of colon should be sufficient for a match.

Comment: You are correct the OP did stipulate that but it doesn't hurt to be careful and the OP also specified anchoring text on both sides so again being safe doesn't hurt. None of that means this doesn't work for the given case though.

Answer (score 0):

Full running awk solution. Hope it helps.

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN {
  while (getline < "file1")
  {
    split($0,dat," ");
    a[dat[1]]=dat[2];
  }
}
{
  gsub(substr($1,2,length($1)),a[substr($1,2,length($1))],$0); print
}' file2
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll do something like that in bash:

```
while read -r key value
do
  echo s/($key:/($value:/g >> sedtmpfile
done < file1
sed -f sedtmpfile file2 > result
rm sedtmpfile
```

Comment: `read -r key value <<< "$line"` is much better than the `cut` games. That `cat` is a [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat). And the expansion of `$sedExpr` should be quoted (i.e. `"$sedExpr"`).

Comment: This also doesn't ensure that only the correct portions of the replacement file will be changed.

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account your comments